# JsonArray Nested Object -> Gson

Tags: java, json

I have this Json File:

```
{
  "code": "#0",
  "data": {
    "list": [
      "Chris",
      "Matt"
    ],
    "time": 1453318488122
  },
  "millis": "1453492643260"
}
```

In Java using Gson how do I access the "data" part, then "list" and turn it into an ArrayList? I have tried looking online and they are all showing things way too complicated for what I want, like serializing a class into Json. I don't want that.. How do I access "List" array inside of "data" object and put into an ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

```
JsonObject fullObject = new JsonParser().parse(yourFileData).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject data = fullObject.getAsJsonObject('data');
JsonArray dataList = data.getAsJsonArray('list');
```

From there you can use `dataList` and iterate the elements.

Comment: Than-yo so much! Worked perfect! I'm sure I tried this but idk :D. Btw ' doesn't work in java, you mean " :D

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize/deserialize such JSON without any additional adapter classes if you define a class like this one.

```
class MyPojo {
  String code;
  long millis;
  Data data;

  static class Data {
    List<String> list;
    long time;
  }
}
```

(+ eventually `@SerializedName` annotations if your strategy requires them)

Comment: I don't get it? Isn't there a simple way I can just take that JsonArray List and turn it into an ArrayList right there? I'm sure there is... I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: If all you need is to extract List from a json text then just take a look at @NG's answer.